# IntersectionObserver breaks on page refresh, but only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's a short demo of the problem:

[image]

I am using IntersectionObserver to make a responsive scrollspy Table of Contents navbar. As you can see, the IntersectionObserver breaks whenever I refresh the page. However if I click to a different page and then come back to it, it works again.

This is my code for the intersection observer:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useIntersectionObserver = (setActiveId, toc) => {

  console.log("intersectionObserver")

  const headingElementsRef = useRef({});

  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    // callback starts
    const callback = (headings) => {
      console.log("callback")
      headingElementsRef.current = headings.reduce((map, headingElement) => {
        map[headingElement.target.id] = headingElement;
        return map;
      }, headingElementsRef.current);

      const visibleHeadings = [];
      console.log("useref", headingElementsRef.current)
      Object.keys(headingElementsRef.current).forEach((key) => {
        const headingElement = headingElementsRef.current[key];
        if (headingElement.isIntersecting) visibleHeadings.push(headingElement);
      });
      console.log("visible headings", visibleHeadings);

      const getIndexFromId = (id) =>
        headingElements.findIndex((heading) => heading.id === id);

      if (visibleHeadings.length === 1) {
        setActiveId(visibleHeadings[0].target.id);
        console.log("visibleHeading", visibleHeadings[0].target.id)
      } else if (visibleHeadings.length > 1) {
        const sortedVisibleHeadings = visibleHeadings.sort(
          (a, b) => getIndexFromId(a.target.id) > getIndexFromId(b.target.id)
        );
        setActiveId(sortedVisibleHeadings[0].target.id);
        console.log("sortedVisibleHeading", sortedVisibleHeadings[0].target.id)
      }
      
      
    };
    //callback ends

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
      rootMargin: "-90px 0px -40% 0px",
    });

    const headingElements = Array.from(
      document
        .getElementById("content")
        .querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
    );
    // const headingElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"));
    console.log("headingElements", headingElements)
    headingElements.forEach((element) => observer.observe(element));
    

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
      headingElementsRef.current = {};
    };
    }, [toc]);
  // });
};

export default useIntersectionObserver;
```

On examining the `headingElementsRef.current` console logs I find that the after page refresh I get this:

```
dataflow-canonical-forms: IntersectionObserverEntry
boundingClientRect: DOMRectReadOnly {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}
intersectionRatio: 0
intersectionRect: DOMRectReadOnly {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}
isIntersecting: false
isVisible: false
rootBounds: null
target: h2#dataflow-canonical-forms.chakra-heading.css-6rvmc6
time: 5277.20000000298
```

Notice how boundingClientRect is 0 all the way.... which is really weird. Any ideas on why this is?

The only fix I have found so far is to remove the dependencies array from `useEffect` but I don't think that is very optimal from a performance point of view...

Answer (score 0):

I think the values for DOM Node properties such as boundingClientRect are only available once the component is mounted. This would explain why it works when you navigate between soft routes, whereas it breaks on refresh.

You'll want to make sure that you are running your code at the proper stage of the react lifecycle by using `componentDidMount()`

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for more details

Comment: I tried wrapping the function called in useEffect with a useTimeout, and that is a hacky way to avoid the problem that boundingClientRect is 0, but I still don't understand how the problem is arising. Obviously the component is already mounted because the headings are available only through `document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")` , but the element or parent element has no dimensions?

Comment: In my opinion, your question really highlights the issue. I think the reason boundingClientRect is returning 0 is because even though the DOM Node exists, the page content hasn't loaded on your page yet. In the traditional JS world, this distinction is very similar to the difference between DOMContentLoaded  vs load event listeners. To get the height, you don't just need the document on the front end, the content also needs to be rendered, right??